# How to assign LIST class models Nested in Web API 2.0

Tags: c#, nested, postman, asp.net-web-api2

I need help, to Assign List Nested Web Api 2.0:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] ZHitung1m respon1)
```

So far my code only can Assign First Class Model

I can assign and call                 `= respon1.DistCode`
but somehow I cannot assign and call  `= respon1.ProductCode`

Here my Models class WEB Api :

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace WebAPI.Models
{
    public class ZHitung1m
    {
        public string DistCode { get; set; }
        
        public List<ZHitung2m> Row { get; set; }

        public class ZHitung2m
        {
            public string ProductCode { get; set; }
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my API Controller `use HttpResponseMessage Post =`

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using WebAPI.Models;

namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class Zhitung1Controller : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] ZHitung1m respon1)
        {

            var variable1 = respon1.DistCode;

            if (variable1 == "anton")
            {
                respon1.DistCode = "budiman";
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, respon1);

        }
        }
}
```

So far I just can only assign (`respon1.DistCode`)
How to call and assign (`respon1.ProductCode`)?

Without changing nested structure in my POSTMAN,
here my postman Result:
[image: want keep nested structure like this]

1. Anyone know to call and assign (`respon1.ProductCode`)?
   So far I try

```
public class ZHitung2m : ZHitung1m
{
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
}
```

Its change and broke postman structure that I want.

2.

```
 public class ZHitung1m : ZHitung2m
 {
     public string DistCode { get; set; }
     
     public List<ZHitung2m> Row { get; set; }

 }
 public class ZHitung2m
 {
     public string ProductCode { get; set; }
 }
```

Use this class models code, can call assign (`respon1.ProductCode`)
but also change and broke postman structure that I want:

[image: postman2]

Comment: Can you change the sending end?  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/json-and-xml-serialization#anonymous-and-weakly-typed-objects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making your models inherit from each other doesn't seem like what you want to do at all, as they are representing different concepts, i.e. `ZHitung1m` contains a list of `ZHitung2m`, if you're inheriting one from the other you're saying `ZHitung1m` is a type of `ZHitung2m` or vice versa.

So no inheritance needed... then try something along these lines (changing variable names to something descriptive):

```
namespace WebAPI.Controllers
{
    public class Zhitung1Controller : ApiController
    {

        [HttpPost]
        public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] ZHitung1m respon1)
        {

            var variable1 = respon1.DistCode;

            if (variable1 == "anton")
            {
                respon1.DistCode = "budiman";
            }

            foreach(var row in respon1.Row)
            {
                var variable2 = row.ProductCode;

                ... do something with variable2 or row here ...
            }

            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, respon1);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so Much, David House, your answers is Correct, i try it your code, & i can call / assign List Nested (row.ProductCode)